# webbrowser control within class library executing RDS-can't change internet settings and trusted site does not work

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, rds

I have been working on **this problem** for a week:

I have a class library that hosts a .net webbrowser control.  This webbrowser control kicks off a vbscript which uses RDS technology to communicate with a database.  Everthing works fine if I change my internet options to 'allow datasources accross domains'.  However, this is not an option when deployment happens due to obvious security concerns.  The problem then is getting the solution to work WITHOUT changing the global ie settings.

**Things I have tried**:
*Adding the site that we access via RDS to our 'trusted sites' (didn't make a difference)
*Researched the custom security manager for the webbrowser control 
*To find any other way to make this work besides the custom security manager since documentation seems lacking and it is tricky to implement

**Where I need help**:
The custom security manager seems to be the way to go but I am having to pull from multiple posts and there seem to be gaps in how to implement it with c# in the .net framework.  I am having some trouble getthing started here.  I think if I had some footing of namespaces and project references that I might be able to use some other posts I have found which seem to provide the coding portion of the IInternetSecurityManager.  There seems to be a need to override a base class, then inherit that from another base class, but I am having trouble there.  So I need helping getting started if possible, and then be able to ask questions along the way after I get going.

**What I would like to understand**
It seems the webbrowser control is not safe for scripting, so that it doesn't EXACTLY mimic IE.  I wonder if there is a way to up the permissions on my class library, or register it, or give more permissions to the webbrowser control without having to implement the custom security manager?

HELP PLEASE.  I'M DROWNING IN THIS :)